# Changing try-it out url in swagger-ui docker

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I tried to hook up swagger-ui for my application with docker, the "try-it-out" url is pointing to localhost:8080, is there a way to specify the try url? Below is my docker-compose configuration.

```
swagger:
    image: "swaggerapi/swagger-ui"
    depends_on:
      - application-xxx
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - API_URL= http://0.0.0.0:52204/swagger.json
```

And here is the docker image I have been using: https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-ui/

Comment: What are the `host` and `port` in your swagger.json file?

Comment: I believe thats inside the image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui. The image I have been using is a publicly hosted one, just wondering if there are ways to change the try-out url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was, I had a space in between API_URL= and the url like below: 
 API_URL= http://0.0.0.0:52204/swagger.json

After I removed the space the try-out-url is pointing to what I configured.